# Specify filename in ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

For file storage, I'm using a custom ContentProvider cobbled together from a few examples I found online. It seems to be working pretty well as long as I use one file name defined in the class itself (mImageName), but I need to be able to define the file name with a parameter outside of the class itself. Can someone help me with this? Here is a snippet of my ContentProvider class:

```
public class FileStorageContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

static final String AUTHORITY = "content://com.jwburnside.provider";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(AUTHORITY);
private static final HashMap<String, String> MIME_TYPES = new HashMap<String, String>();

private String mImageName = "myImage";

static {
    MIME_TYPES.put(".jpg", "image/jpeg");
    MIME_TYPES.put(".jpeg", "image/jpeg");
}

public FileStorageContentProvider() {}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {

    try {

        File mFile = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(),mImageName);
        if(!mFile.exists()) {
            mFile.createNewFile();
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI, null);
        }

        return (true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

And in my activity:

```
mImageCaptureUri = FileStorageContentProvider.CONTENT_URI;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll usually specify things like that as part of the URI that gets passed to your methods. So you'd use something like

```
mImageCaptureUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(FileStorageContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, "myImage");
```

Then inside your various methods (like `query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)`) you can extract the filename from the URI with `uri.getPath()`.

Comment: Great, thanks that works partially. One more question: Is createNewFile() being called too early? This class is created on startup because of the manifest provider definition, and I can't pass the URI parameter in onCreate() as you have described, so I can use the path as the file name.

Comment: It does seem like you're calling that too early, yes. Everything depends on your own use case, of course, but I'd probably do the creation only on `update()` and `insert()`, and then have the other methods not assume that the file exists (so fail gracefully if it doesn't).